# How to send data from kinect SDK 2.0 Visual Studio to ROS turtlebot 3?

Tags: ros, communication, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im new to ROS. How would I go about sending gesture data / skeletal data or any data to ROS turtlebot 3 from visual studio for the Kinect 2.0 sdk.

My goal is to send a gesture from the Kinect (e.g. wave my hand and that tell that turtle bot 3 to move forward). I want to be able to control multiple turtlebot 3's, but getting one would be good enough for now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329098/how-to-send-data-from-kinect-sdk-2.0-visual-studio-to-ros-turtlebot-3?/) by [humzaChoudry](https://answers.ros.org/users/44167/humzachoudry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite to connect you VisualStudio Project with ROS.

or if you have a Windows 10 you could try to use this http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows and develop a ROS node

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0